# Will my PC go to sleep while rendering

Tags: rendering

Just as the title says, if I leave a video rendering overnight and don't change my pc's sleep settings will the pc sleep AFTER the render or will it sleep DURING?

Another way to ask this is if Blender works like Youtube and sends a signal to the PC to NOT sleep while it's doing something?
In Youtube's case: playing a video
In Blender's case: Rendering a video

Comment: Consider testing this yourself. Set the computer go into sleep mode if idle for 1min (or whatever) and set it to render something that takes longer than 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to chance it and left my PC on over a night

Turns out it stayed on whilst rendering
Actually, turns out just having blender running at all keeps my PC on

I'd recommend just having blender open and seeing if your PC falls asleep or not,
before trying to render and leave it on, so that the system doesn't suddenly shut down while a process is running

Comment: You're right. I just tried it again and this time windows didn't go to sleep. That's great news, thanks for checking :).

Comment: im rendering in blender 3.1 on windows 7 and the pc will go to sleep and interrupt the render process.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is: it depends. You have to test for your machine.

On Windows alone it depends on the sleep settings, but also power settings and other group policies and other things more or less hidden away.

All these can be heavily influenced by many factors.

Brand computers - especially laptops - have often custom settings that are not always exposed.
Some softwares installed by the user might also influence this, especially those who claim to "boost" or manage performances and graphics in any way.