Blender animation render in cycles slows down over night
Currently, I'm rendering 520 frames in cycles (4 to 5 mins a frame) so about 39 hours, naturally I try to render when I sleep for efficiency. I have done this many times before successfully.
When I woke up this morning I saw that only a single frame was rendered in 8 hours ar a totally random time. 
I turn my monitors off before going to bed and I feel like it either has to do with this (I would not know why this would effect performance; again I've done this successfully before this way) or, it has to do with some windows power settings.

Either way, I am at a loss trying to figure out why only this single frame would render at 7am but nothing else.
Anyone have any idea what might cause something like this to occur?
PS. Just remembered I updated my blender from 3.6 to 4.2 yesterday, just extra info in case it is a possible effector. [Win 11 - 7950x3D - 4080 -32ddr5, always stable temp 60 to 70 while rendering]
[Solved] Thank you everyone for your comments. "Turning off monitors can make Window believe there are no monitors attached", this made the difference, just let 1 monitor on that goes black after a while on its own. Don't know what could cause this, because this never used to happen.

Turning off monitors can make Window believe there are no monitors attached, which depending on the render engine may affect rendering speed

Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260615/is-there-render-setting-to-prevent-pc-suspend

It also depends on what you're rendering. When I render a smoke simulation and the smoke builds from frame to frame, there are more and more volumetrics to render which makes each frame slower. Or let's say you're approaching a planet displaced with Adaptive Subdivision. Sure, far away things have less resolution, but the closer you get the more the planet might fill the frame, i.e. more displacement has to be calculated. I don't say your animation is anything like this, but we know nothing about it and I just wanted to show there can be several single or combined reasons then.

Of course only a single frame being rendered over night is probably not (solely) dependent on the animation itself. I had several times now where 4.2 (you said you updated) got stuck even in simple scenes, so maybe the current stable release is not yet so very stable after all.

Make sure you check all your render settings are still the same between versions too. I remember once this happened to me cause I was rendering with CPU in one version, then switched to another version and somehow it got set to using GPU but with the same CPU small kernel size. GPU/CPU render kernel sizes are like polar opposites. So my overnight render was basically stuck doing hundreds of samples on CPU optimized kernel sizes with a GPY, and it only got to one frame overnight.

Mind you this was like Blender 2.7 or something, and it wouldn't be like this now cause Cycles uses adaptive sampling these days, but this issue reminded me of that and maybe it's related to some render setting mismatch. Especially since you said you switched versions.

I'm also having this issue. Rendering starts strong at about 2 mins a frame, after about 100 frames or so, it slows down to 4 mins a frame for no reason. My computer is plugged into a TV, and I turn it off overnight when rendering, but as far as windows is concerned, it should definitely see it as plugged in. I don't have the PC sleep or anything, and power mode is set to high performance at all times.
Definitely seems like a bug or something.
